# How to retrieve all the values from a custom arraydapter

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

i have implemented a custom array adapter for my project,so far i am able to add and delete items from it and it displays them in the ListView too
dynamically..however i have a button in the MainActivity(that holds the ListView), that when clicked i want to display all the row items.
so far what i am getting instead of the data in the adapter after appending all values to a StringBuilder is: 
**com.baseadapter.C@4052b9b8com.baseadapter.C@4052f490com.baseadapter.C@40531378com.baseadapter.C@4053415**

the arrayadapter and arraylist are set as below:

```
ArrayList<C> arrayvalues= new ArrayList<C>();
MyAdapter adapter;
adapter= new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item,
            arrayvalues);
```

the code for my collection class is this:

```
public class C {

    String the_text;    
    public String getText() {
    return the_text;
    }

    public void setText(String the_text) {
    this.the_text = the_text;
    }

 public C(String the_text) {
 super();
 this.the_text = the_text;
}
}
```

the code i use to iterate over the adapter is this:

```
btn_done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0 ; i<adapter.getCount() ; i++){
                  b.append(adapter.getItem(i));
                }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), b.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

and the custom adapter code(just in case,though i don,t think the problem lies here):

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<C> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<C> data = new ArrayList<C>();

public MyAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
ArrayList<C> data) {
super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
this.context = context;
this.data = data;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View row = convertView;
myholder holder = null;

if (row == null) {
LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
holder = new myholder();

holder.tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_num);
holder.btnDelete = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

row.setTag(holder);
} else {
holder = (myholder) row.getTag();
}
C c=data.get(position);
holder.tv.setText(c.getText());
//String c=data.get(position);
//holder.tv.setText(c.g.getName());


holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 data.remove(position);
 notifyDataSetChanged();
}
});
return row;

}

static class myholder {
    TextView tv;
    ImageButton btnDelete;
    }

    }
```

what should i do to get the actual values in the adapter?ps:kindly attach code,thanks

Comment: Override the `toString()` method in your C class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your below loop code. it shall work now.

```
   for(int i=0 ; i<adapter.getCount() ; i++)
     {
        C itemObject=adapter.getItem(i);
        if(itelObject!=null)
          b.append(itemObject.getText());
     }
```

Comment: thanks it worked man,lacking in reputation to accept the answer but when i do,i will,thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should override the **getItem()** method in the Adapter:

```
@Override
public C getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}
```

And update your loop code to get the text for "C" or override "C" toString() method as was suggested.